# How do I change a subscriber schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication

I am currently working on a prototype to allow a client to update a subscriber database schema so that they can eventually change the subscriber to match the new version of their application then switch over to that database when they deploy the front end code.

My hope was that I could issue schema changes (for example, change a column data type) while keeping the replication stored procedures up to date to properly convert any replicated data. While the subscriber might hold locks on big tables being updated it could then just queue up the changes from the publisher instead of causing locking issues with the still-running application. I hope I'm explaining this well enough...

Here's what I tried:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

UPDATE dbo.Big_Table SET some_string = REPLACE(some_string, ',', '')

ALTER TABLE dbo.Big_Table ALTER COLUMN some_string INT

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'create procedure [dbo].[sp_MSins_dboBig_Table]
    @c1 bigint,
    @c2 varchar(20),
    @c3 varchar(30)
as
begin
    declare @c2_new int

    set @c2_new = cast(replace(@c2, '','', '''') as int)

    insert into [dbo].[Big_Table] (
        [my_id],
        [some_string],
        [another_string]
    )
    values (
        @c1,
        @c2_new,
        @c3
    )
end    -- '

EXEC(@sql)

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

This specific script would change a `VARCHAR` column that contains numeric data into an `INT` while at the same time removing any commas that might be included in a number like "1,325".

The problem is, this causes blocking at the publisher as well. I've seen [references to pausing replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151783%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), but none of them have concrete steps to follow (I don't have a lot of replication experience). It's typically, "turn off some jobs".

I also saw a [page on switching updating modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146938%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), but I *think* that only applies to update-able subscribers.

Any suggestions on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

How do you have replication set up now if the publisher and subscriber schema don't match?  This is a really "interesting" setup.  In general, messing with the default procedures is going to cause a headache.  Because they're system maintained, your new version could be overwritten at any point (though in practice, this wouldn't happen).  If you don't have an updating subscriber, the subscriber should be treated as read-only lest you break replication.  Perhaps I'm missing something, though.

Comment: The schema matches currently. I'm actually trying to change the subscriber schema *after* transactional replication is set up. I thought that the stored procedures were the standard way of setting up heterogeneous replication. Is this not the case? In 2000 and 2005 it was through DTS packages, but that support was dropped in 2008. Again, I thought that functionality was replaced with the stored procedures and customizing those. BTW, these types of questions should probably be handled in comments on the question.

Comment: You can provide your own stored procedure for the subscription.  Just don't change the one that MS generates for you.  To provide your own procedure, specify a value for ins_cmd, del_cmd, and/or upd_cmd in your call to sp_addarticle.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll look into that to make sure that I'm doing things the right way. I don't think that this will help with the locking problem though.